# Multiple language database issue

Tags: android, sqlite

The function below that i just added three new language table, may i know can it work like localization method. Same like "values, values-zh,"..

```
private static final String TABLE = "PLANT";
private static final String K_ID = "ID";
private static final String K_NAME = "NAME";
private static final String K_BEN = "BENEFIT";

//column of chinese table
private static final String TABLE_ZH = "PLANT_ZH";
private static final String K_ID_ZH = "ID_ZH";
private static final String K_NAME_ZH = "NAME_ZH";
private static final String K_BEN_ZH = "BENEFIT_ZH";

//column of india table
private static final String TABLE_HI = "PLANT_HI";
private static final String K_ID_HI = "ID_HI";
private static final String K_NAME_HI = "NAME_HI";
private static final String K_BEN_HI = "BENEFIT_HI";

//column of malay table
private static final String TABLE_MS = "PLANT_MS";
private static final String K_ID_MS = "ID_MS";
private static final String K_NAME_MS = "NAME_MS";
private static final String K_BEN_MS = "BENEFIT_MS";
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " (" + K_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + K_NAME + " TEXT , " + K_BEN
                + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('ALOE (Aloe Vera)','This plant has hundreds of uses, the most popular being its ability to alleviate the pain of burns and to speed their healing. Immediately immerse the burn in cold water or apply ice until the heat subsides, then generously apply the aloeAloe may also be applied to any cut or skin abrasion, and onto skin eruptions, remarkably speeding healing. To relieve the pain and itching of hemorrhoids, carve out a suppository sized chunk of the inner leaf gel and insert into the rectum.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('GARLIC (Allium sativum)','Best known for its antibiotic effect, garlic bulbs or the milder garlic greens can be eaten raw at the onset of a cold or flu. Garlic oil is effectively used for ear infections. It is easily made by finely chopping enough fresh organic garlic bulbs to fill a jelly jar, and covering them with organic olive oil.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('GINGER (Zinziber officiale)','Ginger has a carminative effect, which means that it will help relieve digestive problems which result in gas formation. It is also a diaphoretic, used both as a tea and added to a soaking bath to stimulate sweating and reduce fevers.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('COCONUT','White meat and water from the cavity are used for heart conditions, dysentery, fever, pain, and digestive and bladder problems, to quench thirst and as an aphrodisiac. To treat diarrhea, meat from young fruits is mixed with other ingredients and rubbed onto the stomach. Oil prepared from boiling coconut milk is thought of as antiseptic and soothing and so is smoothed onto the skin to treat burns, ringworm and itching.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('Carallia Brachiata','The bark was extracted with petroleum ether, ethyl acetate and methanol successively. All the extracts were screened for wound healing activity by excision and incision models in Wistar rats. The ethyl acetate and methanol extracts were found to possess significant wound healing activity. The extracts revealed the presence of sterols or triterpenoids, flavonoids, phenols, tannins, carbohydrates, fixed oils and fats.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('Ficus Hispida','The fruits are bitter, refrigerant, astringent, acrid, anti-dysenteric, anti-inflammatory, depurative, vulnerary, haemostatic and galactagogue. They are useful in ulcere, leucoderma, psoriasis, anaemia, haemorrhoids, jaundice, epistaxis, stomatorrhagia, inflammations, intermittent fever and vitiated conditions of pitta.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('Leea Indica','A decoction of the root is given in colic, is cooling and relieves thirst. In Goa, the root is much used in diarrheal and chronic dysentery. The roasted leaves are applied to the head in vertigo. The juice of the young leaves is a digestive. Plant pacifies vitiated pitta, diarrhea, dysentery, colic, ulcers, skin diseases, and vertigo.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('Mesua Ferrea','Flowers are acrid, anodyne, digestive, constipating, and stomachic. They are used in treating asthma, leprosy, cough, fever, vomiting and impotency. The seed oil pacifies vata, and also good for skin diseases and rheumatism');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('Trema Orientalis','It has been used for medicinal purposes including the treatment of respiratory, inflammatory, and helminthic diseases. Almost every part of the plant is used as medicine in various parts of Africa.');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME
                + ","
                + K_BEN
                + ") VALUES('Murraya Paniculata','The decoction of the leaves can be used as a gargle to treat toothache. The leaves are frequently used to treat pain due to scalding. This decoction can be given orally to treat body aches, as a tonic, and for expelling tape worm');";
        db.execSQL(sql);

        String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZH + " (" + K_ID_ZH
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + K_NAME_ZH + " TEXT , " + K_BEN_ZH + " TEXT,);";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('芦荟','这种植物有上百种用途，最常见的是用来减轻灼伤的疼痛并有效加快他们的治疗。当灼伤时，立即浸入冷水烧伤或冰敷，直到发热消，然后温柔地应用芦荟在任何伤口或皮肤擦伤，和皮疹，这能显着加速愈合。为了减轻痔疮的疼痛和瘙痒，能开出内叶凝胶的栓剂大小的块，将其插入直肠.');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('大蒜','最好的就是其抗菌效果,蒜头或温和的大蒜蔬菜可以在感冒或流感的发病生吃.大蒜油被有效地用于耳部感染.大蒜很容易被细切,并将新鲜有机蒜头放进果冻罐,以及用机橄榄油覆盖它们而制成.');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('姜','生姜具有驱风作用，这意味着，这将有助于缓解其导致气体形成的消化问题。这也使人发汗，同时用作茶叶并加至浸浴刺激出汗和减少发烧');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('椰子','白色的肉和水腔用于心脏疾病,痢疾,发烧,疼痛,消化和膀胱问题，解渴,并作为春药.治疗腹泻,从幼果肉中混合其他成分和擦在胃.从沸腾椰奶制成油被认为是防腐和舒缓,并因此被平滑到皮肤,以治疗烧伤，癣瘙痒.');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('竹节树','树皮用石油醚,乙酸乙酯和甲醇依次萃取.所有的萃取液在雄性大鼠中筛选用于伤口愈合的活动由切除和切口模型.的乙酸乙酯和甲醇的萃取物发现具有显著伤口愈合活性.将萃取揭示固醇或三萜,类黄酮,酚,丹宁酸,糖类,固定油类和脂肪的存在.');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('叶榕','果实是苦的,制冷剂,涩,辛,抗痢疾,消炎,净化剂,伤药,止血和催乳.他们可以使用在溃肠,白癜风,牛皮癣,贫血,痔疮,黄疸,鼻衄,口出血,炎症,间歇性发热和八色鸟的污浊病症.');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('火筒树','果实是苦的,制冷剂,涩,辛,抗痢疾,消炎,净化剂,伤药,止血和催乳.他们可以使用在溃肠,白癜风,牛皮癣,贫血,痔疮,黄疸,鼻衄,口出血,炎症,间歇性发热和八色鸟的污浊病症.');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('铁力木','花是辛辣的，有效止痛，帮助消化，解决便秘和健胃。它们用于治疗哮喘，麻风病，咳嗽，发热，呕吐和阳痿。种子油帮助瓦塔，并且也有利于治疗皮肤病和风湿病');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('山黄麻','它已被用于药用目的,用于治疗呼吸道,炎性和寄生虫疾病.这个植物几乎每一个部分都被用作药物在非洲的各个部分.');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        sql1 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_ZH
                + ","
                + K_BEN_ZH
                + ") VALUES('九里香','煎煮的叶子可用作漱口以治疗牙痛。叶子通常用于治疗烫伤的疼痛。这煎剂可以口服治疗全身酸痛，作为补品，并驱逐带虫');";
        db.execSQL(sql1);

        String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HI + " (" + K_ID_HI
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + K_NAME_HI + " TEXT , " + K_BEN_HI + " TEXT,);";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('मुसब्बर','संयंत्र का उपयोग करता है के सैकड़ों है，सबसे आम जलने के दर्द से छुटकारा पाने और प्रभावी ढंग से उनके इलाज में तेजी लाने के लिए किया जाता है，जब जला दिया, तुरंत गर्मी के उन्मूलन तक ठंडे पानी या बर्फ जला में डूबे，फिर धीरे काफी उपचार में तेजी लाने सकता है, जो किसी भी घाव या त्वचा abrasions,और चकत्ते में मुसब्बर वेरा लागू,बवासीर के दर्द और खुजली को कम भीतरी पत्ती जेल वर्तिका ब्लॉक आकार बाहर उत्कीर्ण है, और मलाशय में डालने के लिए.');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('लहसुन','सबसे अच्छा अपने जीवाणुरोधी प्रभाव , हल्के लहसुन या लहसुन सब्जियों सर्दी या फ्लू की शुरुआत में खाया जा सकता है । लहसुन तेल प्रभावी ढंग से कान में संक्रमण के लिए प्रयोग किया जाता है । लहसुन जेली में ठीक -काट और ताजा जैविक लहसुन होना आसान है डिब्बे, और बना जैतून का तेल मशीन के साथ उन्हें कवर।');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('अदरक','अदरक यह गैस गठन के लिए नेतृत्व जो पाचन समस्याओं को दूर करने में मदद मिलेगी जिसका मतलब है कि वातहर प्रभाव पड़ता है। यह भी ' पसीना उत्तेजित और बुखार को कम करने के लिए स्नान के लिए कहा दोनों चाय के रूप में और , पसीना आता है');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('नारियल','दिल की बीमारी , दस्त , बुखार, दर्द , पाचन और मूत्राशय की समस्याओं, प्यास, और एक कामोद्दीपक के रूप के लिए सफेद मांस और पानी चैम्बर। अन्य सामग्री के साथ मिश्रित दस्त, समझो और पेट में युवा से लुगदी रगड़ें। नारियल के दूध उबलते तेल से बना है यह एंटीसेप्टिक और सुखदायक माना जाता है , और इस');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('बांस के पेड़','पेट्रोलियम ईथर, एथिल एसीटेट और नर चूहों में सभी निकालने निकाले मेथनॉल क्रमिक रूप से बार्क एथिल एसीटेट और मेथनॉल अर्क के छांटना और चीरा मॉडल के आधार पर घाव भरने गतिविधि के लिए जांच की गई एक महत्वपूर्ण घाव भरने पाए गए गतिविधि। निकालने triterpenoid स्टेरॉयड या flavonoids , फिनोल, टैनिन , शक्कर, तय तेल और वसा की मौजूदगी का पता चलता है ,।');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('नंदी','फल कड़वा , शीतल, कसैला , तीखा , विरोधी दस्त, विरोधी भड़काऊ, शुद्ध एजेंट , करनेवाला , खून बह रहा है और प्रोलैक्टिन है । वे आंतों के अल्सर , विटिलिगो , सोरायसिस, एनीमिया , बवासीर, पीलिया में इस्तेमाल किया जा सकता है, नाक से खून आना , मुंह से खून बह रहा , सूजन , रुक-रुक कर बुखार और पित्त गंदा परिस्थितियों ।');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('आग ट्यूब पेड़','तीव्र पेट दर्द में प्रयोग किया जाता है जड़ काढ़े, प्यास शांत करने के लिए इस्तेमाल किया जा सकता है। गोवा में जड़ें दस्त और पुरानी पेचिश के लिए उपयोग किया जाता है । भुना हुआ पत्तियों चक्कर के सिर में सुलझाया जा सकता है । रस पाचन में मदद कर सकते हैं पत्तियां दवा। इस संयंत्र गंदा pita , दस्त, पेचिश , पेट दर्द , अल्सर , त्वचा रोग, सिर का चक्कर मध्यस्थता करने के लिए प्रयोग किया जाता है ।');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI

                + ") VALUES('Mesua फेरिया','फूलों कब्ज और पेट को हल , पाचन में मदद , मसालेदार, प्रभावी दर्द कर रहे हैं । वे अस्थमा, कुष्ठ रोग , खांसी, बुखार , उल्टी, और नपुंसकता के इलाज के लिए उपयोग किया जाता है । बीज का तेल वात में मदद करता है , और यह भी त्वचा रोग और गठिया के इलाज के लिए अनुकूल है');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('Trema Orientalis','यह श्वसन भड़काऊ और परजीवी रोगों के उपचार के लिए , औषधीय प्रयोजनों के लिए प्रयोग किया गया है । लगभग इस संयंत्र के हर हिस्से अफ्रीका में दवा के प्रत्येक भाग के लिए इस्तेमाल कर रहे हैं');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_HI
                + ","
                + K_BEN_HI
                + ") VALUES('मुराया paniculata','पत्तियों के काढ़े दांत दर्द के इलाज के लिए एक कुल्ला के रूप में इस्तेमाल किया जा सकता है। पत्तियां आमतौर पर जलता दर्द के इलाज के लिए उपयोग किया जाता है । इस उपचार एक टॉनिक के रूप में , मौखिक रूप से काढ़े शरीर में दर्द दिलाई , और परजीवी के निष्कासन की जा सकती है');";
        db.execSQL(sql2);

        String sql3 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MS + " (" + K_ID_MS
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + K_NAME_MS + " TEXT , " + K_BEN_MS + " TEXT,);";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('ALOE','ai beratus-ratus kegunaan , yang paling biasa adalah untuk melegakan kesakitan terbakar dan berkesan mempercepatkan penyembuhan. Apabila terbakar, luka bakar segera tenggelam dalam air sejuk atau ais, sehingga demam hilang, kemudian perlahan-lahan memohon lidah buaya dalam mana-mana luka atau melecet kulit, dan ruam , yang ketara boleh mempercepatkan penyembuhan. Untuk mengurangkan rasa sakit dan gatal-gatal buasir, mengukir daun gel supositori blok bersaiz dalaman, dan masukkannya ke dalam rektum.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Bawang putih','Yang terbaik adalah kesan anti-bakteria , bawang putih atau bawang putih ringan sayur-sayuran yang boleh dimakan pada awal selesema sejuk atau . Minyak Bawang putih berkesan digunakan untuk jangkitan telinga. Bawang putih adalah mudah untuk menjadi mewah yang dipotong dan bawang putih organik segar ke dalam agar-agar tin, dan meliputi mereka dengan mesin minyak zaitun dibuat.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Halia','Halia mempunyai kesan yg mengeluarkan udara , yang bermaksud bahawa ia akan membantu untuk mengurangkan masalah pencernaan yang membawa kepada pembentukan gas. Ini juga menjadikan berpeluh, kedua-dua sebagai teh dan ditambah untuk mandi untuk merangsang peluh dan mengurangkan demam');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Kelapa','Daging putih dan ruang air untuk penyakit jantung , cirit-birit , demam, sakit , pencernaan dan pundi kencing masalah , dahaga , dan sebagai afrodisiak. Merawat cirit-birit , dicampur dengan bahan-bahan lain dan sapu pulpa dari muda di dalam perut. Santan diperbuat daripada minyak mendidih dianggap sebagai antiseptik dan menenangkan, dan oleh itu terlicin ke dalam kulit untuk merawat luka terbakar , gatal-gatal kurap.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Carallia Brachiata','Ekstrak kulit kayu, petroleum eter , etil asetat dan metanol. Pengekstrakan semua aktiviti pemeriksaan oleh pemotongan luka model penyembuhan dan cutout tikus Wistar . Of etil asetat dan metanol ekstrak didapati mempunyai aktiviti penyembuhan luka yang ketara. Steroid Dipetik kehadiran atau perubatan, flavonoid , fenol , tanin , karbohidrat , minyak biasa tetap dan lemak.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Ficus hispida','Buah ini pahit, penyejuk, astringen, menusuk hidung , anti- cirit-birit , anti -radang, ejen pembersihan, pengobat luka , pendarahan dan prolaktin. Mereka boleh digunakan dalam usus ulser, vitiligo , psoriasis , anemia , buasir, penyakit kuning, epistaxis , pendarahan mulut, keradangan , demam sekejap dan pita keadaan kotor.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Leea Indica','Merebus akar digunakan dalam sakit perut akut , boleh digunakan untuk menyejukkan dahaga . In Goa , akar digunakan untuk cirit-birit dan disentri kronik. Daun panggang boleh diselesaikan ke dalam kepala gayat. Daun jus boleh membantu penghadaman perubatan. tumbuhan ini digunakan untuk menjadi pengantara pita kotor , cirit-birit , disentri , sakit perut , ulser , penyakit kulit, gayat.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Pokok Penaga Lilin',' Mempunyai bunga yang pedas, kesakitan yang berkesan , membantu pencernaan, menyelesaikan masalah sembelit dan perut. Ia digunakan untuk merawat asma , kusta , batuk , demam, muntah-muntah, dan mati pucuk. Minyak biji membantu Vata , dan juga kondusif untuk rawatan penyakit kulit dan sakit sendi');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Trema Orientalis','Ia telah digunakan untuk tujuan perubatan, untuk rawatan pernafasan, radang dan parasit penyakit. Hampir setiap bahagian tumbuhan ini digunakan sebagai ubat-ubatan di pelbagai tempat di Afrika.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        sql3 = "INSERT INTO "
                + TABLE
                + " ("
                + K_NAME_MS
                + ","
                + K_BEN_MS
                + ") VALUES('Murraya Paniculata','Air rebusan daun boleh digunakan sebagai minuman keras untuk merawat sakit gigi. Daun biasanya digunakan untuk merawat sakit terbakar. Rawatan ini boleh ditadbir secara lisan sakit badan merebus, sebagai tonik , dan pengusiran parasit.');";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
    }

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE +TABLE_ZH+TABLE_HI+TABLE_MS);
    onCreate(db);
}

}

/**
 * Upgrade database
 */
public void Reset() {
    dbHelper.onUpgrade(this.db, 1, 1);
}

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param ctx
 *            the activity context
 */
public DBHelper(Context ctx) {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}

/**
 * Open database connection
 *
 * @return the database connection
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public DBHelper open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

/**
 * Close database connection
 */
public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

When i use this createEntry method, how do i actually call for store in both         TABLE?? Same as below method, i dont know how to use it for both table.Because it is same thing but different string different id.

```
public boolean createEntry(String name, String benefit) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(K_NAME, name);
    cv.put(K_BEN, benefit);
    return db.insert(TABLE, null, cv) != -1;
}

public boolean updateEntry(String name, String benefit, String id) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(K_NAME, name);
    cv.put(K_BEN, benefit);
    return db.update(TABLE, cv, K_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }) > 0;
}

public PlantList getList() {
    PlantList plants = new PlantList();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + K_ID + " ," + K_NAME + " FROM "
            + TABLE, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            plants.addData(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(K_ID)),
                    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(K_NAME)));
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    cur.close();
    return plants;
}

public PlantList getQuery(String query) { //search data
    PlantList plants = new PlantList();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + K_ID + " ," + K_NAME + " FROM "
            + TABLE + " WHERE " + K_NAME + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'", null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            plants.addData(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(K_ID)),
                    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(K_NAME)));
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    cur.close();
    return plants;
}

public String[] getDetail(String id) {
    String data[] = new String[2];
    Cursor cur = db.query(TABLE, new String[] { K_NAME, K_BEN }, K_ID + "="
            + id, null, null, null, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        data[0] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(K_NAME));
        data[1] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(K_BEN));
    }
    cur.close();
    return data;
}

public String getName(String id) {
    String name = null;
    Cursor cur = db.query(TABLE, new String[] { K_NAME }, K_ID + "=" + id,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(K_NAME));
    }
    cur.close();
    return name;
}

public boolean deleteEntry(String id) {
    return db.delete(TABLE, K_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }) > 0;
}
```

Comment: You can just change the names of the tables (PLANT, PLANT_ZH ...) and keep the names of the columns the same - each table will have columns ID, NAME, BENEFIT.

Comment: Yes i did it, but i do not know how to use the localization method at here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did is create four different databases, as files in the res folder. At first app startup, the appropriate db file gets copied to the database. When the user changes language on the device, the database is stored as a file on the file system, and the database with the proper language gets loaded, either from res or from the file system. Unfortunately, this required an app restart. Which is ok if language changes are very rare.

Another solution would be to create a number of databases and dbhelpers, one for each language. You write a layer in your app that uses the proper database and -helper. This causes multiple databases to exist on the device, but it doesn't require a restart.

Comment: I have just updated my code.I need to let user to choose the language of the system, after that my system will change to selected language system. Now i don't know what is the method to load my Different Language TABLE, i had already inserted all my different language plant data. I just want to load it to display selected language data.

Comment: Don't apologize for your English, we all appreciate the effort you make. As for your database, I guess you can just have different tables, and add a layer to your sql code to query the proper table depending on the language the app or the user has chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Look here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

under /values

> XML files that contain simple values, such as strings, integers, and colors.
>
> Whereas XML resource files in other res/ subdirectories define a
>   single resource based on the XML filename, files in the values/
>   directory describe multiple resources. For a file in this directory,
>   each child of the `<resources>` element defines a single resource. For
>   example, a `<string>` element creates an R.string resource and a `<color>`
>   element creates an R.color resource.
>
> Because each resource is defined with its own XML element, **you can
>   name the file whatever you want** and place different resource types in
>   one file. However, for clarity, you might want to place unique
>   resource types in different files. For example, here are some filename
>   conventions for resources you can create in this directory:

You may put any table names or other stuff in one of the folders values, values-in , ... and keep the column names the same. Then use the standard resource retrieval mechanisms of Android. See here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: Sir, i don't understand the part of putting any table names or other stuff in values folder.

Comment: @MrLister: Wow, you seem to have a lot of time, when editing documentation that originally came from googles developer guide.

Comment: @Hühnergott Don't ask.